# Can I build local http server?

Tags: c#, c++, http

I need to build a local fake http server. It will listen all my http request and will decide which packet will be dropped or forward or delayed. Can I do that ? If I can how can I do it ?

Comment: sounds more like a proxy than a "http server"

Comment: Is this the same question as your earlier http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4151617/c-c-capture-local-machine-ip-packet-and-drop-it ?

Comment: No, that one on packet filtering. But here I want to know how to build local http server.

Comment: I see no reason why you couldn't do it. Did you really mean to ask a yes/no question? Maybe you should ask what you *really* want to know. If there's some part of the task that's giving you trouble, ask about *that*.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say how can I do it ?

Comment: @Barun: Do you mean any outgoing HTTP request (to some other server) or requests going specifically to your local server (localhost/127.0.0.1)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I do that ?

Yes

> If I can how can I do it ?

First, make a socket server:

http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-simple-threaded-tcp-server

Next, parse HTTP and respond to it (linked in HTTP/1.0 for simplicity):

http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1945.txt

As for "dropped or delayed", a "web server" does not operate at a packet level, you will have to clarify what you need it to do.

Comment: Thanks for reply. How just saw that link you post. Seems very easy. Now how is it possible that it will listen all my http request ?

Comment: Barun: It uses magic to do so.  Write an http server that listens to the requests, and it'll magically do so.